# HTML Web.py Web framework Simple Category search

Tags: python, html, sqlite, web.py, web-frameworks

I am trying to create a search filter for categories. The problem, among others, is how the python select is not working the way I mentally would like it. In SQLite I want SELECT * FROM Auctions WHERE Category='arg'. This works on the database when I enter say toys where arg would be. 
I have category in a dropdown but am unsure how to extract the value. If the search form is used I would like it to just show what category was selected for now and then will work on the price fields. I'm just trying to figure out the web.py way to do this. Heres what I have. This is a school project.

Form:

```
    FilterForm = web.form.Form( 
       web.form.Textbox('Search', web.form.notnull, description="Search:"),
       web.form.Dropdown(name='Category', args=[]),
       web.form.Textbox('minPrice', web.form.notnull, description="Price Min: "),
       web.form.Textbox('maxPrice', web.form.notnull, description="Price Max: ")
       web.form.Button('Apply Search Filter')
    )
    def POST(self):
    if not FilterForm.validates():
        Auctions = model.filter_auctions(FilterForm.d.Category, FilterForm.d.maxPrice, FilterForm.d.minPrice)

        FilterForm.Category.args = [(a.ItemID, a.Category) for a in Auctions]
        return render.index(Auctions,
                AuctionForm,
                Bids,
                BidForm,
                Logins,
                LoginForm,
                FilterForm,
                TimeForm)
    raise web.seeother('/')
```

Model:

```
    def filter_auctions(category, price_min, price_max):
        return db.select('Auction', where="Category=category")
```

HTML:

```
 <ul id="filtermenu">
     <li><a href="#">Add Filter</a><span class="rarrow">&#9654;</span>
        <ul class="subF1">
           <form action="" method="post">
             $:FilterForm.render()
           </form>
        </ul>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

So this ended up being a typo and after reading the man pages things became more clear. If someone runs into a similiar issue I will at least post what worked.The model

Model:

```
def filter_auctions(category, price_min, price_max):
    return db.select('Auction', where="Category=$category AND Price>$price_min 
    AND Price<$price_max", vars=locals())
```

Form:

```
if FilterForm.validates():
    Auctions = model.filter_auctions(FilterForm.d.Search,   FilterForm.d.Category, FilterForm.d.minPrice, 
    FilterForm.d.maxPrice)
```